# Multiple authentication providers (same schema) - do not go further if one is sucсeed? NET 7

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, jwt, authorization

So, I has two authentication schemas:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddJwtBearer("LocalJWT")
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(jwtOptions =>
                    {
                        jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
                    },
                    identityOptions =>
                    {
                        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", identityOptions);
                    },
                    subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true
                );
```

LocalJWT - to local JWT authorization, and Microsoft Identity Web Api - for JWT authorization using Azure AD.

My authorization:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Basic", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("LocalJWT", JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build());

        options.FallbackPolicy = basicPolicy;
    });
```

What I want to do - if authentication/authorization using local JWT is succeeded - system will not go further and check using Azure AD.

But, with current solution, I receive and error "Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/secret/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'"

It's expected, because I don't have specific Azure AD tenant - that's a requirement for the future. However, I need to leave that for now.

Any ideas?